# SSL packet format - OpenSSL?

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl

I'm using OpenSSL to establish a secure connection. I want to inspect the header of enctypted packets to access the length of the packet before actual decryption.
I'm using DTLSv1_method() and I saw the standard description of the record (according to https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4347) should be:

```
struct {
    ContentType type;
    ProtocolVersion version;
    uint16 epoch;                                     // New field
    uint48 sequence_number;                           // New field
    uint16 length;
    select (CipherSpec.cipher_type) {
        case block:  GenericBlockCipher;
    } fragment;
} DTLSCiphertext;
```

So, in the example packet in the picture, I'm able to address the header (cyan) and access the length (red), which in this case is 48 bytes.
[image: Example data packet]

In an handshake packet I see the header is different and length is in a different position. [image: Example handshake packet]

My question is: since I can't find this information around OpenSSL documentation, are there OpenSSL defined constants to describe data and handshake records' headers so that i don't have to access them with hardcoded numbers such as

```
int headerLenght = 13 // bytes
read(11) // discard
uint16 sslPacketLength = read(2)
...
```

?

Comment: The RFCs document the record formats and field values.

Comment: Thank you but actually the question is about OpenSSL and if there is a way to access header metadata from the library. As pointed out I've already looked at the RFC document...